# OpenID API for both asp.net and JavaScript support?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

*I've been struggling a lot lately to find decent solution which has authentication mechanism for server  and client API's.*

I put alot of effort trying to find working(!) code samples , but couldn't find any.
The code from *DotNetOpenAuth* doesn't work for me - im using vs 2010 .net 4 webform

Anyway , I can't seems to find a solution which covers  an overall  API for all parameters/providers and it seems that I have to build it from scratch.

*For example —* ( [google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)) : Every solution I've found provides only the *info* that  the basic url is :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
```

[image]

Also , i don't know if this usage is going to work since I've heard that the service is [*deprecated*](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) :

[image]

But this will never work alone , since I have to append URL parameters :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
 scope=email%20profile&
 state=%2Fprofile&
 redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback&
 response_type=token&
 client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Why do I have to build/encode it by myself ?

Now , I don't have a problem with  the parameters filling , I have a problem with the fact that I can't find full API for both client (js) and server side (.net).

It seems that I have to build the url + encoded values by myself

**Question**

Is there any solution which will take as param my plain values , and will provide final valid URL   ?

(both for C# and js/jq and for many providers )

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? Because I have same problem and I have just started bounty.

Comment: @JeetenParmar no my friend , still waiting for an answer .

Comment: Keep checking my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057939/login-using-goolge-oauth-2-0-with-c-sharp
if someone gives perfect reply then it will help both of us.

Comment: hey, I have solved this issue. Check my post. And dont forget to do up vote on my post and on answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this request in Ajax with jQuery, you can use the "data" parameter to pass those values and jQuery will ensure that everything is kosher.

If the request is a POST, it will add it to the body or append it to the URL if it's a GET request.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/