# Login using Google OAuth 2.0 with C# - using async code

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

About this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057939/login-using-goolge-oauth-2-0-with-c-sharp) (Login using Google OAuth 2.0 with C#), I have not understood how to use

```
async void getgoogleplususerdataSer(string access_token)
```

I need to retrieve the e-mail and where should I put this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it somewhere at the end of the login flow, when your server already has an access token. The call is present in the code you linked, it is just commented out, just take a closer look at their `Page_Load` implementation.

Btw. Such manual Oauth2 implementation possibly works, however, there are frameworks that implement all possible OAuth2 flows saving you from such lengthy, error prone code. Consider DotNetOpenAuth for example, I wrote a tutorial on how to login with Google using DNOA. The last part is email retrieval when the access token is available.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simple-oauth2-federated-authentication.html

Comment: This is the error when I uncomment the line: "[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that t..."

Comment: Your solution is perfect. Thank you