# WebSecurity login with google

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, websecurity

I am working with net MVC application project.
I used WebSecurity (using WebMatrix.WebData) for login into my web application.

How to use external login such as Google login, Facebook login using websecurity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login using Google OAuth 2.0 with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057939/login-using-google-oauth-2-0-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I know the OAuth2.0 login using google. But login with google using Websecurity.