# How to get logged email via OAuth 2.0 in C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheet API V4 in C#.
My source will create new Excel file, write data to that file.

When execute, Google API will open a new OAuth tab on the browser, User will choose/login to an email on this tab, and grant Read/Write/All permission for my App.

My question is: How can I get Logged/permitted email address in C# source?
I want to know, what email did the user log in to create myfile.xlsx.

Thanks in advance.
Code snippet:

```
string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.DriveFile };
string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API";

UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
    new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
    // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "UserName",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}

var fileName = "myfile.xlsx";

var myNewSheet = new Spreadsheet();
myNewSheet.Properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
myNewSheet.Properties.Title = fileName;

var sheet = new Sheet();
sheet.Properties = new SheetProperties();
sheet.Properties.Title = $"data";

myNewSheet.Sheets = new List<Sheet>() { sheet };

var newSheet = service.Spreadsheets.Create(myNewSheet).Execute();
var spreadSheetId = newSheet.SpreadsheetId;
...........
// Write data to file source
```

Answer (score -1):

### Google Indentiy platform describes the procedure of how to [authenticate a user](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#authenticatingtheuser) to obtain [user information](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo) and more specifically [user profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtaininguserprofileinformation)

- The documentation does not specify how exactly to do it in C#, but basically

  - Make a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`
  - Provide the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`
  - There is a good [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713360/11599789) on Stackoverflow how to do it in PHP - I hope it helps you with the implementation in C#
- There is also a workaround [authenticating users with Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602183/11599789)