# Google - C# WinFormsApp - Auth

Tags: c#, google-authentication

I have a question,
Is it possible to use Google user accounts for authentication in WinFormsAPP?

I need to write an application in C# Winforms that reads user-specific data from a database.

Is there an easy way to authenticate using Google?
I might be able to store a list of valid Google users in my database, or maybe I can even define a list of valid application users in Google?

Is there perhaps already a sample project for this case somewhere? I actually can't believe that I am the first developer with such a requirement...

I am grateful for any help or suggestion!

Comment: Sure. You can use OAuth. Here are samples from google: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[Integrating "Sign In With Google" Functionality To An Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrating-google-sign-in-into-your-web-app/)

[Login using Google OAuth 2.0 with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057939/login-using-google-oauth-2-0-with-c-sharp)